# Ionic2 saving data cache

Tags: cordova, caching, ionic2

Hello everyone I'm listing some datas with *ngFor from mongojs and i will put a network checker with navigator Cordova Apache but if the user is offline they need to see the saved datas(when they were online).I dont want to save them to localStorage it is a bit difficult to save all of them separately, what is the way to do that i'm a bit new with ionic2.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ionic-cache for this, this package will store your request in cache for an specific time you have to define and then it will retrieve the request from cache instead of your api also you can can activate a feature to keep the data stored valid when the device get's offline. check the repo [here](https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply  I ll try and tell the results

Comment: @erdemgünenç any results ?

Comment: I  apologies couldn't try it yet, I got some error on client side from different page, but whenever it finishes I'll try and let you know.By the way thanks to your reply now I know what to use.Thank you   @Alberick0

Comment: @erdemgünenç were you able to check this ? if this answer was helpful to you, please consider marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: I did apologies I forget it my bad.Thank you for your accepted reply.

Comment: You welcome @erdemgünenç, on the question there's a check icon, you can click on that to mark the answer as the right one for you question. :)